# Infinite loading when executing a command in an asp file

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, windows-server-2003

```
Set oShell = Server.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C copy ""C:\inetpub\test\test.txt"" ""C:\inetpub\test\test2.txt"" ", 0, true
```

Hello, I try to run any command from an asp file on my Windows 2003 server but none of them work, my test page loads endlessly when it is executed.

I have already tried to put the pool application in local system but nothing changes.
Have you seen this before ?

Comment: Try directing the command to a text file and see what the output is `> log.txt`. It likely going to be a permission issue.

Comment: I just tried but nothing happens, no log file is created

Comment: Is that all the code or is it possible you have `On Error Resume Next` set somewhere which is hiding the error?

Comment: What's the identity of application pool? Try to use local system and administrator, to check if it work.

Comment: What is the username that run the website?  That username must be logued onto the server.  If the server is at logon page, or logued with another account, your script won't run.  Running any batch/executable is not recommended and won't works in many case.  What are your needs?  You must find another way to do them.

Comment: I understand this is not answering your question directly, but if you want to copy a file why couldn't you use Scripting.FileSystemObject 

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_copyfile.asp